# C# - Change socket protocol from tcp to udp

Tags: c#, sockets, serialization, tcp, udp

I made a program which send serialized datas from a server to several clients using a tcp Socket. This protocol makes the manipulation too complicated for my users *(first connect to server before anything can happen)* and I would like to use a udp socket but I can't find anything to easily learn how to do that (and keed the xmlSerializer instead of a byte[]). 
Here is my code for the TCPListener creation :

```
public void CreateListener()
    {
        TcpListener tcpListener = null;
        try
        {
            tcpListener = new TcpListener(LocalIpAddress(), 8000);
            tcpListener.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(@"Can't create Listener");
        }
        while (!_shouldStop)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);

            if (tcpListener != null)
            {
                TcpClient client = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
                _clients.Add(client);
            }
            Console.WriteLine(@"clients : " + _clients.Count);
        }
        tcpListener?.Stop();
    }
```

And here are my methods to send and receive datas :

```
public void SendDatas()
    {
        XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof (DataSet));
        foreach (NetworkStream ns in from TcpClient client in _clients 
                   where client.Connected select client.GetStream())
        {
            xml.Serialize(ns, Controler.Database.DataSet);
            ns.Close();
        }
    }

    public void ReceiveDatas()
    {
        XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof (DataSet));
        foreach (TcpClient client in _clients)
        {
            if (client.Connected)
            {
                NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream();
                var ds = (DataSet) xml.Deserialize(ns);
                /* treatment*/
                ns.Flush();
                ns.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Client non connecté !!");
            }
        }
    }
```

Thank you, Menaren

Comment: No; you don't want to use UDP.  UDP does not guarantee message ordering or delivery, so you'll have to do lots of work just to make sure data arrives.

Comment: You should use Signalr.

Comment: SLaks.  There is no difference in ordering between TCP or UDP.  Both use IP routing which is the same.

Comment: @jdweng http://serverfault.com/a/8984

Comment: What I said is correct and agrees with webpage.  The UDP doesn't send a receipt.  The ordering is the same since the datagram number is in the IP header and is guaranteed in both UDP and TCP.

Comment: @SLaks Thank you for answering, I don't really need ordering ( I only send datas once) but will there be a problem with the entirety of the DataSet during the transfer? I also can re-send the datas at any time so so udp is not a problem, I just want to simplify the use of my program for the users.

Comment: UDP and TCP both require connection before anything can happen except if the UDP is broadcast.  Broadcast message is limited to work only in a subnet and will not work outside a subnet because routers usually block broadcast messages outside a subnet.  It would use TCP which Is reliable because of the receipt and retry capability.

Comment: @jdweng: you are giving a lot of bad information here. TCP and UDP are _very_ different; TCP is a stream of ordered bytes. UDP is message-based, where the messages themselves are not guaranteed to arrive in any particular order, or at all, or just once. That they are both based on the underlying IP protocol is irrelevant (not that IP itself guarantees ordering anyway...having a datagram number doesn't impose an order on the delivered datagrams). Furthermore, UDP is connectionless, so saying that it requires a connection is just about as wrong as a person can get.

Comment: The choice of TCP vs UDP should be based on specific communications requirements, not on the question of what's "too complicated" for your users. That said, if you _are_ going to base in on what's "too complicated", TCP is ultimately _less_ complicated because it imposes more structure on the communication (more structure == fewer things to get wrong). Both TCP and UDP are non-trivial to use correctly; there are plenty of "gotchas" in both, so if your users aren't up to the task, consider using a higher-level approach, such as AJAX, web sockets, etc.

Comment: Peter you are confusing the issues.  I'm a very experience network engineer and have read the RFC specifications.  Don't get messages and datagrams confused where datagrams are parts of longer messages.  The order of messages are never guaranteed in either UDP or TCP.  The application layer master/slave relationships handle the message ordering.  The datagram ordering when you have more than one datagram per message is handled the same in both UDP and TCP.  Normally TCP message are longer than UDP, but not always.

Comment: How shall your server know whereto "send serialized datas" if the clients won't connect anymore?